# What kind of logic React Hooks are there to handle?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am dealing with a conceptual question in my mind. When thinking about `frontend` and `backend` it comes to my mind that frontend is a presentation layer for what backend passes to it. In terms of smart and dumb, frontend is dumb and backend is smart. Since all the business logic is going to be handled in backend.

By frontend I mean a react application, and by backend I mean a node/express application.

So If I am trying to authenticate a user, react just renders a login form, while express handles authentication logic such as:

- validating username
- querying user in the database
- verifying whether username matches its password

and so on...

(It is obvious that frontend is also do a validation on both username and password, but it is just a early check)

On the other hand, react `hooks` are there to handle (business?) logic. I can not imagine what kind of logic hooks are going to manage. The ones which are related to business rules, or the ones that are related to presenting a view to end user? Are they just responsible for requesting to a backend service or ... ?

Why I am asking this is because I am trying to find a way to have a core logic repository of all business rules so that I can share it between my react and react-native application to achieve what they are saying, `learn once, write anywhere`. If I am going to write react anywhere I have to have a way to share my core logic as well to prevent from duplication which leads to ease of maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you got the right picture what hooks are meant for.

React hooks are just a way to...

- make a part of your component code reusable
- move a part of your component code into its own "area"

I can write a hook to handle client-side pagination because I want to reuse it:

```
const usePagination = ({itemsTotal, itemsPerPage}) => {
    // ...
    // some magic here
    // ...
    return { next, prev, sliceStart, sliceEnd, currentPage, pagesTotal };
}
```

Or I can write a one-shot hook to fetch the data for one of my views just to move the nitty-gritty details of dealing with the API out of my render function. So this is not done for re-usability, just as a way to structure my code:

```
const useFooAPI = () => {
    // this is just a sketch
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const [error, setError] = useState();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState();
    useEffect(() => axios.get('bla/bla/foo').then(response => setData(response.data)), []);
    return {data, error, isLoading};
}
```

So IF you need some of the business logic to be placed in the front-end you might use hooks, because -as you have stated- it provides a way to ensure your different components use the same logic. BUT hooks are not your only way of having shared code/logic. In a nutshell, if you do not base your hook on other hooks (i.e. somewhere deep inside a hook chain you will find a useState, or useEffect, or some of the other original react hooks) then strictly speaking you don't have a hook, just a vanilla js function.

So this is not a hook:

```
const useLegalAge = (userAge, locale) => {
    if (locale === 'US')
        return { isLegalAge: userAge >= 21 };
    else
        return { isLegalAge: userAge >= 18 };
}
```